# git - How can I tell where a repo will "push" to?

Tags: git

I've got an old repo on my machine that I cloned some time ago, and want to know where it would push to if I ran:

`git push`

How can I tell where it will push to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To display the URL of `origin`:

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
```

`origin` which is where `git push` (with no parameters) will push to. The command `git remote show origin` will also list branch information. The push location can be overridden if you've set `branch.*.remote` for the current branch.

You can also run `git push --dry-run`, which will show you more information about what the push will do. Also, you can manually specify the remote repo by adding it as a parameter to the `push` command.

Comment: thanks for the feedback... well the thing is i'd like this to also work for the case where I don't have anything to push - I really want to just see where the remote that it would push to is... I tried it on my repo that had no changes in it, and it responded with "Everything up-to-date"

Comment: Dry-run said that? What did `git remote show origin` dump out?

Comment: it dumped out lots more and seems good to me too.... ```* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://some-test-server/bparks/test-project.git
  Push  URL: https://some-test-server/bparks/test-project.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master rebases onto remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

Comment: That **Push URL:** is where it'll push to. You can also try `git config --get remote.origin.url`, which just displays the URL and not any branch information.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that

`git remote -v`

will show where it will push to....

For example, I ran it in my repo, and it showed the following:

```
origin  https://some_remote_server/bparks/test-project.git (fetch)
origin  https://some_remote_server/bparks/test-project.git (push)
```

which seems to suggest what it would push too...

Comment: Not quite. `git remote -v` just lists the remotes you have set up for that repo.